# How could uptime command show a cpu time greater than 100%?

Tags: linux, profiling

Running an application with an infinite loop (no sleep, no system calls inside the loop) on a linux system with kernel 2.6.11 and single core processor results in a 98-99% cputime consuming. That's normal.
 I have another single thread server application normally with an average sleep of 98% and a maximum of 20% of cputime. Once connected with a net client, the sleep average drops to 88% (nothing strange) but  the cputime (1 minute average) rises constantly but not immediately over the 100%... I saw also a 160% !!?? The net traffic is quite slow (one small packet every 0.5 seconds). Usually the 15 min average of uptime command shows about 115%.

I ran also gprof but I did not find it useful... I have a similar scenario:

```
IDLE SCENARIO
%time name
59.09 Run()
25.00 updateInfos()
 5.68 updateMcuInfo()
 2.27 getLastEvent()
 ....

CONNECTED SCENARIO
%time name
38.42 updateInfo()
34.49 Run()
10.57 updateCUinfo()
 4.36 updateMcuInfo()
 3.90 ...
 1.77 ...
 ....
```

None of the listed functions is directly involved with client communication

How can you explain this behaviour? Is it a known bug? Could be the extra time consumed in kernel space after a system call and lead to a calculus like

```
%=100*(apptime+kerneltime)/(total apps time)?
```

Comment: Where have you got an uptime which shows cputimes as percentages? Normally uptime shows just load averages, e.g.: `15:17:26 up 17 days, 11:36, 12 users,  load average: 0.15, 0.11, 0.09`. Or are you referring to output of `top`?

Comment: Here a recent output of uptime: 15:46:11 up  5:17, load average: 1.25, 1.12, 1.05  (the percentage is just my adjustement: 1.00 = 100%)

Comment: Those numbers are not percentages. They are load averages. See e.g. http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages .

Comment: @SamiLaine In the article you cite I read: "The 100% utilization mark is 1.00 on a single-core system, 2.00, on a dual-core, 4.00 on a quad-core, etc." ... so I think my equation is still valid. The ssh console suffers a bit indeed.

Comment: Yes, but, as you read on, you can see that it's actually the number of processes in the run queue waiting access to cpu, not percentage of cpu usage. Ie. load average of 1.00 for 5 minutes, e.g., means that on average there aren't any processes which have to wait to get to be run on the cpu. Load average of 1.00 for 5 minutes, on a single core cpu, means that there have been on average one process waiting to get to cpu for the whole 5 minutes.